# "Have never been" vs "never was"

Tags: grammaticality, tense, perfect-constructions

"Have never been" or "never was", which one is grammatical in the following context?

> **John**: Hey Subha, can you please make pizza for us tonight?
>   **Me**: You know I ***have never been/was never a*** good cook. We better order it from restaurants.

I think "present perfect" is the correct choice. The reason is that it implies that upto the moment of speaking I am not a good cook. I think ***never was*** can fit in the following context:

> **John**: Hey Subha, do you remeber you made pizza last year? It tasted really bad.
>   **Me**: You know, John, I never was a good cook.

I am a non native speaker. So sometimes it's very confusing for me to choose the correct tense. Can anyone please provide a good example that help me understand the difference between ***never was*** and ***have never been***?

Answer (score 3):

Agreeing with the other answer, here. I would say that either convey what you're trying to say. However, in this case "never have been" may be more accurate because you're saying that you still have *potential* to become a good cook in the future.

On the other hand, the word "was" is typically used to describe something that will not change.

So, "I never was a nice child" as opposed to "I never was a nice person."

You can't change your childhood so it's accurate to say "I never was a nice child".

However, to say "I never was a nice *person*" gives the impression that you can never change... Which means that you're nearing death -- and have no time left to change -- or that you have no intent to change in the future.

You can use both and a native English speaker will understand what you mean. But, technically, the second sentence implies permanence.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL SE! Thanks for writing a good, explanatory answer.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "I was never" cannot change: I was never sick as a child.
"I never have been" suggests 'up to now.' I have never been to Lima. I have never broken any bones. I have never been arrested....

You can also say, "I was never xxxx until now"; "until this happened".